# Magento 2 Override Private method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, override-model

I am working with the Magento2, as per my requirement i want to override the private function.

In `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider` has a method "getCustomerData()" as private one, this function is called as follows

```
public function getConfig()
    {
....
        $output['customerData'] = $this->getCustomerData();
...
}
```

so, now i override this module using preference method

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Vendor\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

In My extended class instead of override the private function i just add "Custom" word to the end of the private function, now the function name in my extended class "getCustomerDataCustom()"

Then in my extended class i called that function as follows

```
public function getConfig()
    {
....
        $output['customerData'] = $this->getCustomerDataCustom();
...
}
```

The issue is the core & extended class are not working.
The module is in enable stage and there is no errors in system and exception log.
May i know what is an issue. Kindly check and share your ideas.
Thanks in advance

Herewith i have added my whole extended class, In this extended class i have override all the private functions

```
namespace Vendor\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool;
use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data as CheckoutHelper;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface as CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrlManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface as LocaleFormat;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface as ShippingMethodManager;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Onepage checkout block
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
    /**
     * @var CheckoutHelper
     */
    private $checkoutHelper;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepository
     */
    private $customerRepositoryCustom;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    private $customerSessionCustom;

    /**
     * @var CustomerUrlManager
     */
    private $customerUrlManager;

    /**
     * @var HttpContext
     */
    private $httpContext;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var QuoteItemRepository
     */
    private $quoteItemRepository;

    /**
     * @var ShippingMethodManager
     */
    private $shippingMethodManager;

    /**
     * @var ConfigurationPool
     */
    private $configurationPool;

    /**
     * @param QuoteIdMaskFactory
     */
    protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    /**
     * @var LocaleFormat
     */
    protected $localeFormat;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper
     */
    protected $addressMapper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config
     */
    protected $addressConfig;

    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface
     */
    protected $viewConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode\ConfigInterface
     */
    protected $postCodesConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $directoryHelper;

    /**
     * @var Cart\ImageProvider
     */
    protected $imageProvider;

    /**
     * @var CartTotalRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $cartTotalRepository;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config
     */
    protected $shippingMethodConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface
     */
    protected $paymentMethodManagement;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutHelper $checkoutHelper
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param CustomerRepository $customerRepository
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param CustomerUrlManager $customerUrlManager
     * @param HttpContext $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository
     * @param ShippingMethodManager $shippingMethodManager
     * @param ConfigurationPool $configurationPool
     * @param QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
     * @param LocaleFormat $localeFormat
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface $viewConfig
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode\ConfigInterface $postCodesConfig
     * @param Cart\ImageProvider $imageProvider
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper
     * @param CartTotalRepositoryInterface $cartTotalRepository
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingMethodConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(

        CheckoutHelper $checkoutHelper,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        CustomerUrlManager $customerUrlManager,
        HttpContext $httpContext,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository,
        ShippingMethodManager $shippingMethodManager,
        ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
        LocaleFormat $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
        FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface $viewConfig,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode\ConfigInterface $postCodesConfig,
        Cart\ImageProvider $imageProvider,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        CartTotalRepositoryInterface $cartTotalRepository,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingMethodConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerRepositoryCustom = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerSessionCustom = $customerSession;
        $this->customerUrlManager = $customerUrlManager;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
        $this->shippingMethodManager = $shippingMethodManager;
        $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
        $this->localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
        $this->addressConfig = $addressConfig;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->viewConfig = $viewConfig;
        $this->postCodesConfig = $postCodesConfig;
        $this->imageProvider = $imageProvider;
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->cartTotalRepository = $cartTotalRepository;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->shippingMethodConfig = $shippingMethodConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->paymentMethodManagement = $paymentMethodManagement;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog_contruct.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Info i get in extended constructor");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    { 
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        $output['formKey'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
        $output['customerData'] = $this->getCustomerDataCustom();
        $output['quoteData'] = $this->getQuoteDataCustom();
        $output['quoteItemData'] = $this->getQuoteItemDataCustom();
        $output['isCustomerLoggedIn'] = $this->isCustomerLoggedInCustom();
        $output['selectedShippingMethod'] = $this->getSelectedShippingMethodCustom();
        $output['storeCode'] = $this->getStoreCodeCustom();
        $output['isGuestCheckoutAllowed'] = $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowedCustom();
        $output['registerUrl'] = $this->getRegisterUrl();
        $output['checkoutUrl'] = $this->getCheckoutUrl();
        $output['defaultSuccessPageUrl'] = $this->getDefaultSuccessPageUrl();
        $output['pageNotFoundUrl'] = $this->pageNotFoundUrl();
        $output['forgotPasswordUrl'] = $this->getForgotPasswordUrlCustom();
        $output['staticBaseUrl'] = $this->getStaticBaseUrl();
        $output['priceFormat'] = $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(
            null,
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getQuoteCurrencyCode()
        );
        $output['basePriceFormat'] = $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(
            null,
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getBaseCurrencyCode()
        );
        $output['postCodes'] = $this->postCodesConfig->getPostCodes();
        $output['imageData'] = $this->imageProvider->getImages($quoteId);
        $output['totalsData'] = $this->getTotalsDataCustom();
        $output['shippingPolicy'] = [
            'isEnabled' => $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                'shipping/shipping_policy/enable_shipping_policy',
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ),
            'shippingPolicyContent' => nl2br(
                $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'shipping/shipping_policy/shipping_policy_content',
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                )
            )
        ];
        $output['activeCarriers'] = $this->getActiveCarriersCustom();
        $output['originCountryCode'] = $this->getOriginCountryCodeCustom();
        $output['paymentMethods'] = $this->getPaymentMethodsCustom();
        $output['autocomplete'] = $this->isAutocompleteEnabledCustom();
        $output['displayBillingOnPaymentMethod'] = $this->checkoutHelper->isDisplayBillingOnPaymentMethodAvailable();
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Is autocomplete enabled for storefront
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function isAutocompleteEnabledCustom()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Form::XML_PATH_ENABLE_AUTOCOMPLETE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) ? 'on' : 'off';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCustomerDataCustom()
    {
        $customerData = [];
        if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($this->customerSessionCustom->getCustomerId());
            $customerMasterId = $customerObj->getMasterId();
            /*$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId()); */
            $customer = $this->customerRepositoryCustom->getById($customerMasterId);
            $customerData = $customer->__toArray();
            foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $key => $address) {
                $customerData['addresses'][$key]['inline'] = $this->getCustomerAddressInline($address);
            }
        }

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(print_r($customerData,1));

        return $customerData;
    }

    /**
     * Set additional customer address data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function getCustomerAddressInlineCustom($address)
    {
        $builtOutputAddressData = $this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($address);
        return $this->addressConfig
            ->getFormatByCode(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config::DEFAULT_ADDRESS_FORMAT)
            ->getRenderer()
            ->renderArray($builtOutputAddressData);
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve quote data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getQuoteDataCustom()
    {
        $quoteData = [];
        if ($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId()) {
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId());
            $quoteData = $quote->toArray();
            $quoteData['is_virtual'] = $quote->getIsVirtual();

            if (!$quote->getCustomer()->getId()) {
                /** @var $quoteIdMask \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMask */
                $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create();
                $quoteData['entity_id'] = $quoteIdMask->load(
                    $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId(),
                    'quote_id'
                )->getMaskedId();
            }
        }
        return $quoteData;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve quote item data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getQuoteItemDataCustom()
    {
        $quoteItemData = [];
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        if ($quoteId) {
            $quoteItems = $this->quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);
            foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItemData[$index] = $quoteItem->toArray();
                $quoteItemData[$index]['options'] = $this->getFormattedOptionValue($quoteItem);
                $quoteItemData[$index]['thumbnail'] = $this->imageHelper->init(
                    $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                    'product_thumbnail_image'
                )->getUrl();
            }
        }
        return $quoteItemData;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve selected shipping method
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    private function getSelectedShippingMethodCustom()
    {
        $shippingMethodData = null;
        try {
            $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
            $shippingMethod = $this->shippingMethodManager->get($quoteId);
            if ($shippingMethod) {
                $shippingMethodData = $shippingMethod->__toArray();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $shippingMethodData = null;
        }
        return $shippingMethodData;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve store code
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function getStoreCodeCustom()
    {
        return $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Check if guest checkout is allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function isGuestCheckoutAllowedCustom()
    {
        return $this->checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($this->checkoutSession->getQuote());
    }

    /**
     * Check if customer is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function isCustomerLoggedInCustom()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    /**
     * Return forgot password URL
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function getForgotPasswordUrlCustom()
    {
        return $this->customerUrlManager->getForgotPasswordUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Return quote totals data
     * @return array
     */
    private function getTotalsDataCustom()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface $totals */
        $totals = $this->cartTotalRepository->get($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId());
        $items = [];
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item */
        foreach ($totals->getItems() as $item) {
            $items[] = $item->__toArray();
        }
        $totalSegmentsData = [];
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\TotalSegment $totalSegment */
        foreach ($totals->getTotalSegments() as $totalSegment) {
            $totalSegmentArray = $totalSegment->toArray();
            if (is_object($totalSegment->getExtensionAttributes())) {
                $totalSegmentArray['extension_attributes'] = $totalSegment->getExtensionAttributes()->__toArray();
            }
            $totalSegmentsData[] = $totalSegmentArray;
        }
        $totals->setItems($items);
        $totals->setTotalSegments($totalSegmentsData);
        $totalsArray = $totals->toArray();
        if (is_object($totals->getExtensionAttributes())) {
            $totalsArray['extension_attributes'] = $totals->getExtensionAttributes()->__toArray();
        }
        return $totalsArray;
    }


    /**
     * Returns active carriers codes
     * @return array
     */
    private function getActiveCarriersCustom()
    {
        $activeCarriers = [];
        foreach ($this->shippingMethodConfig->getActiveCarriers() as $carrier) {
            $activeCarriers[] = $carrier->getCarrierCode();
        }
        return $activeCarriers;
    }

    /**
     * Returns origin country code
     * @return string
     */
    private function getOriginCountryCodeCustom()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config::XML_PATH_ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $this->storeManager->getStore()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of payment methods
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodsCustom()
    {
        $paymentMethods = [];
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if ($quote->getIsVirtual()) {
            foreach ($this->paymentMethodManagement->getList($quote->getId()) as $paymentMethod) {
                $paymentMethods[] = [
                    'code' => $paymentMethod->getCode(),
                    'title' => $paymentMethod->getTitle()
                ];
            }
        }
        return $paymentMethods;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi @senthil, can you please share whole class which you have extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override those private members as well. I can see that function getCustomerData() use **customerRepository** and **customerSession** which are defined as private members in parent class.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: i have done as you mentioned changes, but still the child&parent class method not getting called, i have updated the full extended class code , in this extended class i have extended all my parent class private functions

Comment: Can you please update your question with di.xml which you have used for preference.

Comment: One more thing as you have overridden whole class then why you are changing function name. It is not necessary in this condition. You also not need to override whole class.

Comment: hi @senthil please mark it as solved it worked for you. It'll help others.